# How to know the surfaceview is visible to user?

Tags: android, timer, surfaceview

In my android game, there is a arcade mode, in which the game runs for 60 seconds. The game canvas is a surfaceview. I want the timer to start only when the surfaceview is visible to the user. How to know that the surfaceview is visible so that the timer can be started. Starting timer in surfacecreated method does not help since still it takes some time for the surfaceview to be visible, hence the user looses few precious seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time required for a Surface to be created and become visible should be measurable in milliseconds, not seconds.

The Surface is visible, but blank, when `surfaceCreated()` is called.  What you probably want to do is start the timer after the first `unlockCanvasAndPost()` or `eglSwapBuffers()` call, so that way you know some content is on the screen.

A variation on this would be to set your timer for 61 seconds rather than 60.  Until the clock hits 60, you just show a "Ready?" message on the SurfaceView without really starting the game.  (I do a ready-pause when the game starts and after orientation changes in [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).)

**Edit:** some notes about the interaction between SurfaceView and the Activity lifecycle are [here](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).

Comment: i am starting timer after `unlockCanvasAndPost()` in the surfacecreated method , infact it is the last code to be run in that method. Still sometimes by the time surfaceview is visible the timer moves on to 59 or 58. In your second suggestion, do you mean to say that timer should be started after user responds to a dialog or the timer is actually of 61 sec but i pretend it to be 60 ?

Comment: Don't draw from `surfaceCreated()` -- just use it to advance your game state from "preparing" to "ready", then draw in your render loop.  The last suggestion was more of a workaround -- instead of starting the game with the first frame drawn on the Surface, draw on the Surface for a second or two before the game starts.  Maybe have a "3...2...1...GO!" animation.

Comment: do u think starting the timer thread in `onStart()` will be a solution since `Technically, the activity becomes visible to the user when onStart() is called` as per documentation here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: That should work, though `onPause()` / `onResume()` is probably a better place to manage the thread since you don't want it to continue while the app is paused.  Depending on what you're doing you may not even need a separate thread -- you can use `postDelayed()` to send yourself events that fire after a short delay.